# Error while installing SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express using command line arguments.

The command is

```
E:\UnInstall\SQLServer\SQLServerExpress2008\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe 
       / SQ/SAPWD="testpwd123" /security=SQL /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Enabled"
       /TCPENABLED="1" /NPENABLED="0" /INDICATEPROGRESS="True"
       /INSTANCENAME="CBEInstance" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
```

But after extracting files, when installation begins, it returns following error:

> *SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:*
>
> *The syntax of argument "//" is incorrect. Please use /? to check usage.*
>
> *Error code 0x84B40001.*

Please help.

Comment: Strange! The installer runs from uninstaller folder.

Comment: To make your question more readable, I added a space before every `/` - do you have that in your installation command, too? If not: try adding a space before each `/` to make it **clear** to the installer where your options begin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_x64_ENU.exe / SQ/SAPWD=
              ^___________ Correct this.No need space.
```

And did you mean /QS instead of /SQ?

Comment: Just because I just used this answer:
"The syntax of argument "//" is incorrect. Please use /? to check usage." refers to any syntax failure.  I had a ':' in place of a ';' in my sqlinstall.ini file and it threw the same error.